# Laravel on subdomain - app.domain.com

Tags: laravel-4

How can I get my Laravel app to show on app.domain.com would this be in htaccess? If so how?

I'm not sure if i need to edit the paths.php in the bootstrap folder or can it be simpler by htaccess.

Comment: Anyone willing to help?

Answer (score 3):

what you want is multi tenancy. your server needs to be configured with a wildcard subdomain (*.domain.com), so all your requests still get to your application. and when they hit your application, you decide what to do with the called subdomain.

here an example:

```
Route::group(array('domain' => '{subdomain}.'. Config::get('app.domain')), function() {
    ...
});
```

more about [multi tenancy](http://laravel.com/docs/routing#sub-domain-routing) in the laravel docs.

on your localhost setup you can *cheat* that wildcard scenario by declaring your own sites in your **hosts** file like

```
127.0.0.1   localhost.dev
127.0.0.1   sub1.localhost.dev
127.0.0.1   sub2.localhost.dev
```

wildcards aren't supported for your hosts file

Comment: Yeah it's really a local thing it's on the company I work for domain and it's mapped to a directory, so just by adding this route, would this work?

Comment: if you route your local-fake adresses to localhost in your `hosts` file, it would work. on a server environment you'd do that wildcard subdomain entry (*.domain.com) and all requests would go to your app.

Comment: and wrap that around all my routes?

Comment: yeah, grouping those who need that subdomain identification.

Comment: Tried that and getting 500 Internal Server Error

Comment: I;m not sure how to get them, the server is provided by 1and1.co.uk

Comment: you told me, you were developing on localhost. then you'd need to edit your hostfiles. if you're using an actual server, you'd need to get a wildcard subdomain entry.

Comment: No i said how do i get my laravel app working on app.domain.com this is without giving away any really domain name? Just an example

Comment: your "it's really local thing" made me think it's run locally. anyway, you still need to add a wildcard subdomain, like CNAME entry in your DNS settings. if that is set, your app will work with the above mentioned route definitions.

Comment: Me mistyping I meant to say its not really locally! It's on a server! This chuffing keyboard

Comment: So i basically need to add * in my domain settings then what in laravel?

Comment: in laravel only that route grouping.

Comment: Still unable to get this working, having tried every possible way. All i want to do on a live site domain.com/dev to show my laravel app